# Tags component using UICollectionView with FlowLayout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

What I am trying to do is to put every view on the next line if there is no space. The same principle that Tag libraries are using (think so). I do not want them to scroll just to be on the next line and left aligned. Here is my code:

```
self.collection.register(UINib(nibName: "FlowCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "tag")
    self.collection.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.collection.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.collection.dataSource = self
    self.collection.delegate = self
    let layout = collection.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 18)
```

This is the result

1. With Horizontal scroll direction. Here I have only one row:

[image]

2. With Vertical scroll direction. Here the content is centered which:

[image]

And that's what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Of course the content of the items on the last image is different but I would like items to be left aligned if the tags can't be more than one on the same line.

Comment: Try a variety of different text length. Is it doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

Looks like exactly what you're going for.